# Free JQuery Table Sorting Plugin (with search)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Curious if anybody knows of a free jQuery based table sorting plugin. One where I could filter with a search bar, sort tables by clicking column names etc.

Answer (score 6):

Try this: http://datatables.net/ This is pretty simple to use, has search and sort and is based out of jquery.

Answer (score 4):

Try this for sorting: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ and this for filtering: http://gregweber.info/projects/uitablefilter

Comment: tablesorter doesn't have a search bar does it?

Comment: no, for that, you can use UI Table Filter: http://gregweber.info/projects/uitablefilter